# EJB Local includes Remote

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1, session-bean

Let's assume we are using EJB3 and our session bean uses/implements Local Interface L and  Remote Interface R.

```
@Local
public interface L {
 abstract void localMethod();
}

@Remote
public interface R {
  abstract void remoteMethod();
}
```

**My Question 1**:

can a local client also make use of remoteMethod?

**My Question 2**:

is it good practice to extend the local interface with the remote interface?

```
@Local
public interface L extends R {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. It's not clear what you mean "a local client".  If you have a client in the same process, then it can use both L and R, but you have to lookup/inject them separately: you cannot lookup L, cast to R, and call remoteMethod.
2. I would stop short of calling it a "good" practice.  Parameters and return values of the methods on the remote interface will be pass-by-value but the parameters and return values of the methods on the local interface will be pass-by-reference.  That said, if your EJB and its clients are aware of this caveat, then you can get much better performance by using the local interface when possible.